# Is a read-only HashSet inherently threadsafe?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety

If I initialize a `HashSet<>` inside a `Lazy` initializer and then never change the contents, is that `HashSet<>` inherently threadsafe? Are there read actions that require locking?

Similar Java question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24263521/is-a-collection-threadsafe-if-its-only-written-in-the-constructor) for collections generally, which essentially says yes, but with some caveats (that don't apply in this situation).

Comment: Yes again, if it truly doesn't change and while being constructed isn't accessed, then yes you will be fine. That said, there is nothing stopping someone from changing it, so its "readonly" behaviour is unenforced. Try the immutable collections.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth it's unfortunate that the immutable collections have horrendous performance http://ayende.com/blog/164739/immutable-collections-performance

Comment: @ChrisMarisic The poor performance is quite well known. That said for lots of scenarios the performance issues would not surface. You could always implement your own by wrapping the non-immutable collections internally, which have had many optimisations applied to them over the years.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth how would wrapping something slow ever make it faster? Not to mention hold on to immutability? It's absurdly hard to be immutable in c#. However the code they talk about in Ayende's comments provides interesting constructs to roll your own.

Comment: @ChrisMarisic I meant wrap something like an array or a dictionary in order to roll your own, featuring an API that doesn't allow for change once constructed. I wasn't referring to wrapping the existing immutable types.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, it is. As long as the construction of the `HashSet` object is thread safe, accessing it will always be thread safe as long as the contents doesn't change.

If you [initialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee792409(v=vs.110).aspx) the `Lazy` using [`LazyThreadSafetyMode.PublicationOnly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.lazythreadsafetymode(v=vs.110).aspx) you can be sure the initialization of the `Lazy` is thread safe.

> When multiple threads try to initialize a `Lazy<T>` instance simultaneously, all threads are allowed to run the initialization method (or the default constructor, if there is no initialization method). The first thread to complete initialization sets the value of the `Lazy<T>` instance. That value is returned to any other threads that were simultaneously running the initialization method, unless the initialization method throws exceptions on those threads.

A little code sample:

```
var l = new Lazy<HashSet<string>>( () => new HashSet<string>() { "a" }
                                 , LazyThreadSafetyMode.PublicationOnly
                                 );
```

Comment: While I believe that is, in practice, true, I cannot find a guarantee that non-modifying HashSet operations are threadsafe. In fact the HashSet documentation states otherwise:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx
"Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe."

Do you have evidence that threadsafety is guaranteed in this case?